# Media queries for IE desktop and modern mode

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm creating a landing page and I need it to have slightly different *height* in IE for desktop and modern IE (in Windows 8.1). Can I do that with media queries? I tried binging and googling but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Media queries will help you if you need to respond to the viewport size. For example

```
@media screen and (min-height: 900px) {
  /* rules for tall viewports */
}
```

While you can be sure that IE metro/modern will be the full height of the display, you can't necessarily differentiate that from IE desktop in full-screen mode (i.e. F11), and of course your page may be viewed from a variety of devices with different display dimensions (including rotatable devices in portrait or landscape orientation).